# NaN Error With Printing a `localStorage` Variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following slider duplicated three times, each with different variable names -

```js
var rangeValue = 4;
var chanceoflive2 = 4;


var inputElement = document.querySelector('.range-input');
var submitElement = document.querySelector('.submit');

submitElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML = chanceoflive2;
  localStorage.setItem("chanceoflive2", chanceoflive2);
});

inputElement.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var rangeValue = parseInt(this.value);
  chanceoflive2 = chanceoflive2 || 0;

  chanceoflive2 = rangeValue > 51 ? 2 : 4;
  }
);

function handleClick(){
    alert(chanceoflive2);
}
```

```html
  <main>
    <form oninput="output.value = Math.round(range.valueAsNumber / 1)">
      <h2>
          Choose the Height of Your Building
        </h2>
      <div class="range">
        <input name="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" class="range-input">
        <div class="range-output">
          <output id="output" class="output" name="output" for="range">
            50
          </output>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>

    <a href="chooselength.html"><button type="button" onclick="handleClick()" class="submit">Submit</button></a>
```

Then I have the following page, that adds all the `localStorage` variables and prints them -

```js
console.log(localStorage.getItem('changeoflive1'));
console.log(localStorage.getItem('changeoflive2'));
console.log(localStorage.getItem('changeoflive3'));
console.log(localStorage.getItem('changeoflive4'));

var chanceoflive1 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceoflive1"));
var chanceoflive2 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceoflive2"));
var chanceoflive3 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceoflive3"));
var chanceoflive4 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceoflive4"));

document.getElementById('print4').innerHTML = (chanceoflive1) + (chanceoflive2) + (chanceoflive3) + (chanceoflive4);
```

```html
<p id="print"></p>
```

Although, it just prints `NaN`. Why?

Comment: One (or all) of the strings being parsed is not a number.

Comment: A suggestion, try to put these variables in console.log/alerts and check their values chanceoflive1,(chanceoflive2) ,(chanceoflive3),chanceoflive4); If any one of them are printing non integer then whole summation will be NaN.

Comment: remove parseInt for a moment and then check what you get. There is decent chance that 1 or more value cant be parsed to int.

Comment: I already tried

Comment: Someone told me to put `||0` at the end of where I assign to `innerHTML`, but I didn't quite understand what it meant.